# How to change the color of clicked "<th>" element of table in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

There is a table.

```
<table id="example" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
    <thead style="">
        <tr>
            <th>Lead Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Mobile Number</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="customer in allCustomers track by $index"  >
            <td ng-bind="customer.customerId"></td>
            <td ng-bind="customer.firstName + ' ' + customer.lastName"></td>
            <td ng-bind="customer.phoneMobile=='None'?'':customer.phoneMobile"></td>
            <td ng-bind="customer.email"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I want to bind click on "th" so that when I click on any "th", it got highlited.

Comment: Do u want change text color of clicked th.

Comment: i want to change background color.

Comment: Where's your controller, do you have any click handler on the th already?

Comment: no click handler on th @Jamiec

Comment: Your -ve votes here will be because you've simply showed us your HTML with "show me how to code this". These sort of questions rarely go down well, you should show some effort to have solved this yourself, and perhaps ask a specific question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to highlight it, you can create a TH directive:

```
app.directive('th', function() {
    return  {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: true,
        template: '<span ng-transclude ng-click="highlite = !highlite"></span>',
        link: function(scope, element attr) {
            scope.$watch('highlite', function(val) {
                if (val) {
                    element.addClass('highlite');
                }
                else {
                    element.removeClass('highlite');
                }
            });   
        }
    }
});
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.directive('th', function() {
    return  {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: true,
            template: '<span ng-click="highlite = !highlite" ng-transclude></span>',
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                scope.$watch('highlite', function(val) {
                    if (val) {
                        element.addClass('highlite');
                    }
                    else {
                        element.removeClass('highlite');
                    }
                })
            }
            
    };
});
```

```css
.highlite {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Lead Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Mobile Number</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
  
</div>
```

Comment: removing of class is not working. Please check it on fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/uoLrdc8u/

Comment: You're including the angular script twice: once from jsFiddle, and the other within the script.  Remove one of them. https://jsfiddle.net/uoLrdc8u/1/

Comment: thanks! If I click on other th then it should remove class from existing th